# What is the issue with this LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I was writing a LINQ query to match the existing list with the current query. But It show's me error something like this(**Unable to create a constant value of type 'Vibrant.Areas.Acquisition.Models.BibContentsModel'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.**). Please help me to find out the problem.

**Code**

```
        FinalRRidInt = FinalRRid.Select(int.Parse).ToList();

        List<BibContentsModel> InitData = RRData().ToList();
        var FinalModel = (from aa in db.RecommendResources
                          where FinalRRidInt.Contains(aa.Id)
                          select new
                          {
                              RRId = aa.Id,
                              CurrentTitle = aa.Title,
                              CurrentISBN = aa.ISBN,
                              CurrentAuthor = aa.Author,
                              NewBibContentsModel = (from rr in InitData
                                                     where rr.Title.Contains(aa.Title) || rr.ISBN.Contains(aa.ISBN)
                                                     select new BibContentsModel
                                                                            {
                                                                                RRId = aa.Id,
                                                                                BibId = rr.BibId,
                                                                                Title = rr.Title,
                                                                                ISBN = rr.ISBN,
                                                                                Author = rr.Author,

                                                                            }).GroupBy(asd => asd.BibId).Select(asd => asd.FirstOrDefault())
                          }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new RRModel
                          {
                              RRId = x.RRId,
                              CurrentAuthor = x.CurrentAuthor,
                              CurrentISBN = x.CurrentISBN,
                              CurrentTitle = x.CurrentTitle,
                              NewBibContentsModel = x.NewBibContentsModel.ToList()
                          });
```

**Sql Query method for InitData List**

```
  public List<BibContentsModel> RRData()
    {
        List<BibContentsModel> Initdata = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<BibContentsModel>("select distinct b.id as BibId, stuff((select ' ' + bcc.NormValue from BibContents as bcc where bcc.BibId = b.Id and bcc.TagNo = '245' FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '') as Title,(select top(1) Normvalue from bibcontents bcon where (bcon.tagno='020' or bcon.tagno='022') and bcon.sfld='a' and bcon.bibid=b.id) as ISBN,(select top(1) Normvalue from bibcontents bcon where bcon.tagno='100' and bcon.sfld='a' and bcon.bibid=b.id) as Author from bibs b left join bibcontents bc on b.id=bc.bibid").ToList();
        return Initdata;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Exactly what the error message says...

Comment: I think the problem is with your subquery (from rr in InitData ...)

Comment: Error message: **Unable to create a constant value of type 'Vibrant.Areas.Acquisition.Models.BibContentsModel'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.**

Comment: What type is Author in rr.Author? Is it string or an object?

Comment: Its a string typed property ..

Comment: I think this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539237/only-primitive-types-such-as-int32-string-and-guid-are-supported-in-this-c

Answer (score 1):

The problem most probably lies with your `NewBibContentsModel = x.NewBibContentsModel.ToList()` since LINQ queries do not support referencing of non-scalar variables.

[Referencing Non-Scalar Variables Not Supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx#RefNonScalarClosures)

Answer (score 0):

`InitData` is an in-memory list of `BibContentsModel`s. EF can only handle in-memory lists of primitive values in LINQ queries (as it does with `FinalRRidInt`).

So you must find a way to incorporate the query that obtains `InitData` into the final query. Maybe this can be done by changing

```
from rr in InitData
```

into

```
from rr in RRData()
```

if `RRData()` is an `IQueryable<BibContentsModel>` off the same `db` instance.